# Posting to a file using CURL... Not taking variables

Tags: php

Posting to a file using Curl

I'm trying to post to a file as soon as user enters a website assuming they have clicked from an ad.

Example url = `http://myFabSite.com/?tr=213`

This is what I'm trying but its not capturing the `tr` URL variable or the referrer:

```
if($_GET['tr']){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myFabSite.com/actions/tracksAds.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    $data = array(
        'referrer' => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
        'track_code' => $_GET['tr']
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);    
}
```

trackAds.php:

```
$mysqli = dbConnect();

$referrer = $mysqli->real_escape_string(urldecode(trim($_REQUEST['referrer'])));
$track_code = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['track_code']);

$query = "insert into ad_tracking ( tracking_code, referrer ) VALUES ( '$track_code', '$referrer' )"; 

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Anything obvious?

**UPDATE**

This is from `print_r($data);`

```
Array
(
[referrer] => none
[track_code] => fb1
)
```

This is $query from trackAds.php

```
insert into ad_tracking ( tracking_code, referrer ) VALUES ( '', '' )
```

So, the array is not being passed, either at all or correctly, to trackAds.php

Comment: did you do a `var_dump($data)` to see if it's actually building the array correctly? Plus you're missing `'` quotes on `if($_GET['tr'])`. That won't cause this problem, but it WILL cause syntax warnings.

Comment: ok. so the sending script is getting the GET value properly. did you check if it's actually in $_REQUEST at the other end? And your DB connection is actually working? What's coming out of the real_escape_string() call? BTW: Data in REQUEST/GET/POST are already urldecoded. You're doing a double-decode there, which could potentially mangle the text.

Comment: Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));`.  Sending `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` an array changes the Content-Type to `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found a different method which works ok, still no clue why the other doesn't.

This assumes PHP 5+

```
    $url = 'http://myFabSite.com/actions/tracksAds.php';
    $data = array('referrer' => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'track_code' => $_GET['tr']);

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes in `$_GET[tr]` on the first line. Change it to `$_GET['tr']`.

Also, use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` in `trackAds.php`. There's a great chance here that you are inadvertently getting a cookie value instead of a POST value, or simply have the wrong data in `$_REQUEST`. [See this page in the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order).

Comment: Yep, what he just said. It would be trying to find a define called tr without the quotes.

Comment: @adam: doesn't matter. PHP politely assumes undefined constants to be unquoted strings and auto-stringifies then for you. it will issue a warning, but the code as above would work normally.

Comment: Adding the quotes made no difference

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I updated this answer. I suspect `$_REQUEST` doesn't contain what you expect.

Comment: @EdCottrell I actually switched to post a while a go to see if that was it but it's not. the variables just aren't getting there.

Comment: Any change there are any redirects (.htaccess or otherwise) involved? Also, is `$mysqli` a (PHP built-in) MySQLi object, or a custom class?

Comment: Also, very important: how did you dump out `$query` above? Is that the result of a POST, or did you just load the URL directly in your browser?

Comment: I guess another possibility would be that you are submitting to a location that is redirecting to that script and losing the POST vars in the process? - so you think it's going there, but then a redirect happens? - I had this once submitting to a directory with the assumption it default to index.php. Without a "/" on the end of the directory Apache would redirect and lose the POST vars. Just a thought. Could it be that it's redirecting to www.

@DarrenSweeney - Yep, good point - I forget how smart PHP is some times :))